# Start debugging an xslt application. .net core

Tags: debugging, xslt, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Debugging xslt doesn't work for me if i use .net core. Generated modules system.xml.xsl.compiledquery are not build with debug information.
Debugging with .net framework works, and symbols for system.xml.xsl.compiledquery can be loaded.
Code is similar with example in documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/debugging-xslt?view=vs-2019

[image: csproj file]

[image: Program.cs]

[image: xslt in debug]

[image: Modules window]

[image]

Comment: I create a simple net core project and then copy the sample code under it and then start debugging without any issues. So what is your specific issue? Please describe it in detailed. Besides, you could try to share minimal, reproducible sample your code with us.

Comment: I can't set breakpoint into xslt file. 'No symbols have been loaded for this document'. In the "modules" window for System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.1(2) symbol status is "Binary was not built with debug information". I think that is the problem.

Comment: added some screenshots for better clarifacation.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **Net Core** does not support your way with stepping into the xslt file and only Net Framework could.

The `System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.pdb` will only be recognized and picked up by **Net Framework** while Net Core does not support that.

I think **Microsoft** intends to debug xslt files in `Net Framework` from the very beginning, but did not consider `Net Core`.

So you should report the problem to **Microsoft** and [I have reported this problem to our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1268618/why-cannot-step-into-the-xslt-file-with-net-core-p-1.html). You can check it.

**And** you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more Microsoft's attention. And I hope the Team will give you a satisfactory reply.

**Suggestion**

You can try to debug the new sdk project with net framework:

**1)** open `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
```

**And** then you can step into the xslt file.

Comment: Also, you could try to change your net core project's  csproj file to `<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>`, I think this is the only workaround.